# Userscript should run once, not multiple times

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Test
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://myanimelist.net/*
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
var index = 0;
(function() {
    'use strict';
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log(index);
        index++;
        setTimeout(() => {  console.log(index); }, 2000);
    });
})();
```

So has you can see this code should return in the console : 0 then 1 but
the result is different, actually the script run multiple times.

My only clue is that come from the site in question, any idea ?

[Excepted : (low rep image 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdVtB.png)

[Actual : (low rep image 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZRED.png)

Comment: Runs fine for me with and without using tampermonkey. Are you sure you don't have multiple instances of the script?

Comment: Without test, I see an IIFE plus the `ready(` event. Using slow internet, jquery is not loaded yet (header cache change not yet suceed 200OK), but the IIFE has already tigger since it's pure javascript.

Comment: The site may have iframes which you can test in devtools. Add `// @noframes` in metablock comment. Also you don't need jquery here at all and neither the $(document).ready wrapper.

Comment: `// @noframes` did the job ty ! (Solved)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

your script could be loading for each frame in the page.

add `// @noframes` to prevent this.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Test
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://myanimelist.net/*
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js
// @grant        none
// @noframes
// ==/UserScript==
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use Lodash to run a function once

_.once(
//Function to run only once
)